# ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :id=>nil}, unmatched constraints: [:id]):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I added 'Interest' button to my event show page, which has two views: Display as 
1) 'Interest' if the user didn't have the event in the interest list
2) 'Remove Interest' if the user has added the event to Interest list

However, there is an error with event show pages that were added to the interest list. 'Remove Interest' button/link causes the following errors.

Here's the error messages

> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy",
>   :controller=>"interests", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints:
>   [:id]):

From what I checked this is probably happens because the Interest's ID is not passed on to the interest_path, though I already have it there...

The View

```
    <div class="int-btn">
      <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.interested_events.include?(@event) %>
        <%= link_to interest_path(@interest), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You have removed this event from your interest list" } do %>
          <div class = "btn btn-main m-2">Remove Interest</div>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to event_interests_path(@event), method: :post, data: { confirm: "You have add this event in your interest list" } do %>
          <div class = "btn btn-main m-2">Interested</div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Schema

```html
  create_table "interests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_interests_on_event_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_interests_on_user_id"
  end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
  root to: 'pages#home'

  resources :events do
    resources :interests, only:[:create]
    resources :reviews, only:[:create]
  end

  resources :plans, except:[:destroy] do
    resources :event_plans, only:[:create]
  end

  resources :reviews, only:[:destroy]
  resources :interests, only:[:destroy]

  get 'events/tagged', to: "events#tagged", as: :tagged
end
```

Controllers

```
class InterestsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @interest = Interest.new(interest_params)
    @interest.user = current_user
    @interest.event = @event
    authorize @interest
    if @interest.save
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      render 'events/show', event: @event
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @interest = Interest.find(params[:id])
    authorize @interest
    # @event.user = current_user
    @event = @interest.event
    @interest.destroy
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end

  private

  def interest_params
    params.require(:interest).permit(:user_id, :event_id)
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Please let me know if you have any additional question or if you need anymore info.

Appreciate all your helps!

Comment: Should you not have a destroy action in your resources for the `events:interests`?

Comment: you should try @interest.id instead passing whole object

Comment: What's `@interest`?

Comment: @Diego Did you mean the routes? I have it there.
>>> resources :interests, only:[:destroy]

Comment: @AshokDamaniya I did, but it didn't work.
>> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @SebastianPalma did you mean what /@interest return?
it's a nil

Comment: So, that's the problem @gn2463. `@interest` mustn't be nil, it must be an Interest object.

Comment: then that means your @interest is not initiated properly you should fix it. don't initiate with new it must be database persisted object.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It seems that the reason is because I didn't define @interest in Events Controller.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't use the snippets feature for arbitrary code. Its meant to create running examples for front-end CSS and javascript problems. Indent the code four spaces instead by clicking the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the id off @interest is nil. You probably didn't set the @interest variable correct in the events controller show action. It should be like:

```rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # other code here
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @interest = Interest.find_by(user: current_user, event: @event)
  end
end
```

If this page also can be accessed by users who are not signed in it will give you an error about the current user, to solve that quickly you can adjust it to:

```rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # other code here
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in?
      @interest = Interest.find_by(user: current_user, event: @event)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You're right. 
I didn't set @.interest in Events Controller as you mentioned.
Now it works! Thank you so much!